# How can I use this type of function that sums 3-day sales transactions and counting of 3-day sales transactions and use it in my main logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I know this should be simple but I’m new to programming and could use some assistance in solving this thank you

```
    def daycalc(value, count):
        for row in my_reader:
            cnt = 0
            if row[21] == 'Friday' or row[21] == 'Saturday' or row[21] == 'Sunday':
                tot = tot + float(row[11])
                cnt += 1
            return tot, cnt
        
    
    with open('POS.csv') as csvfile:
        my_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        fricnt = 0
        satcnt = 0
        suncnt = 0
        sun = 0
        door = 0
        hdr = []
        sales = 0
        frisales = 0
        satsales = 0
        sunsales = 0
        total = 0
        totcnt = 0
        for row in my_reader:
            if door == 0:
                hdr.append(row)
                door = 1
            elif row[21] == 'Friday':
                frisales = frisales + float(row[11])
                fricnt += 1
            elif row[21] == 'Saturday':
                satsales = satsales + float(row[11])
                satcnt += 1
            elif row[21] == 'Sunday':
                sunsales = sunsales + float(row[11])
                suncnt += 1
            total = frisales + satsales + sunsales
            totcnt = fricnt + satcnt + suncnt
    
                
    print('3-day Total Sales:',#sum of sales would be here , '3-day Average Sale:', #count would be here)
```

I’ve tried recreating the function differently but I can seem to apply it to my logic and get it to work

Comment: Please show a sample of the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your CSV file looks something like this:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Saturday,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Saturday,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Friday,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Saturday,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Sunday,0
```

Then you could process it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

FILENAME = 'POS.csv'
D = defaultdict(lambda: [0,0.0])
DAYS = ['Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

def show(p, t, c):
    print(f'{p} total={t:.2f} count={c} average={t/c:.2f}')

with open(FILENAME) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        k = row[21]
        D[k][0] += 1
        D[k][1] += float(row[11])
    for day in DAYS:
        if (count := D[day][0]) > 0:
            show(day, D[day][1], count)
    total = sum([D[k][1] for k in DAYS])
    count = sum([D[k][0] for k in DAYS])
    show('Three day', total, count)
```